# Overriding protected abstract method in NSubstitute

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute, spy

I want to create a spy using NSubstitute, but can't find out how after a lot of googling and reading the docs.

The idea would be to have the substitute with an *overriden* method that I could use to monitor received calls, etc. as usual with mocking. But how to achieve this with NSubstitute?

I would prefer not to relax neither `protected` nor `abstract` modifiers.

Here's what I would like to do:

```
[Test]
public void Items_Add_shouldCall_ItemAddedMethod()
{
    var sut = Substitute.For<ItemsRepository>();
    // how to configure???
    sut.Items.Add(Substitute.For<IItem>());

    sut.Received().ItemAdded();  // currently cannot do this

// ...

public abstract class ItemsRepository
{
    public ObservableCollection<IItem> Items { get; set; } 
        = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();

    // ...

    protected abstract void ItemAdded();
}
```

Comment: How about avoiding the substitute all together and create a derived class that exposes the desired functionality

Comment: @Nkosi I want to use a mocking framework in the first place exactly so that I do _not_ need to do that. Since this seems a pretty trivial use-case, I just think there must be a way to do this using the framework.

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/222

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the link. The OP in the example wanted to directly invoke a protected method and verify the result. Instead, what I want to do is to call a public method instead, and verify that a protected method has been called (that is, I want a _test spy_ behavior). I'm afraid the linked issue does not contain an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSubstitute API relies on calling a method to configure it with `Returns` or check `Received()` calls, which means for standard use we can only work with calls that can be invoked via the public API (which excludes `protected` and `private` members). There is no problem with the `abstract` part of your question; it is fine to use NSubstitute with accessible `abstract` members.

Even though C#, by design, prevents us from interacting directly with `protected` members, NSubstitute still records calls made to these members. We can check these by using the ["unofficial"](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/528#issuecomment-475998287) `.ReceivedCalls()` extension:

```
public abstract class ItemsRepository {
    public virtual void Add(int i) { ItemAdded(); }
    protected abstract void ItemAdded();
}

public class Fixture {
    [Fact]
    public void CheckProtectedCall() {
        var sub = Substitute.For<ItemsRepository>();
        sub.When(x => x.Add(Arg.Any<int>())).CallBase();

        sub.Add(42);

        var called = sub.ReceivedCalls().Select(x => x.GetMethodInfo().Name);

        Assert.Contains("ItemAdded", called);
    }
}
```

Other options include creating a derived class (as @Nkosi pointed out), or making the member `internal` instead of `protected` and using `InternalsVisibleTo` to make the member accessible to your test code (if you do the latter I recommend installing [NSubstitute.Analyzer](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to help ensure this is configured correctly).

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I didn't like the "stringly typed" argument in the assertion. I ended up creating a derived mock manually, but instead of using `InternalsVisibleTo`, I extended the mock to contain public numeric properties that are incremented when the (overriden) protected methods are called. But now at least I have more than one alternative to choose from. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it is a good idea to create your own sub-class if you need to mock protected behavior. Moq has a .Protected() Method that allows to mock such Methods, but it also requires you to retrieve the Method by a String. 
And you lose all Type-safety, if you use .Protected().